# Unable to see my windows drives

Tags: hard-drive

`blkid` shows the following

```
swethamadhu@MyPC:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="8E82D4C182D4AF49" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="MyOS" UUID="9812314912312E1E" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="MyData" UUID="0C76D84876D833E4" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="0bac628e-f3a7-4b01-a2d3-e93504d3b5bb" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="d9fcd4e0-54db-46f5-9fc1-b7dd3326c2a9" TYPE="swap"
```

and

```
swethamadhu@MyPC:~$ sudo vol_id --uuid /dev/sda3
sudo: vol_id: command not found
```

Do suggest me what next?

The problem is I am unable to see my windows drives which were shown in Home earlier before some auto updates.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your fstab? Also, I avoid using ntfs file systems on Linux (I've had issues with it in the past).

Answer (score 1):

To view the contents of your ntfs partitions, you have to mount it on a specific directory.

```
sudo mkdir /media/Myos /media/Mydata
sudo chmod a+rwx /media/Myos 
sudo chmod a+rwx /media/Mydata
```

Now mount `/dev/sda2` to `/media/Myos` and `/dev/sda3` to `/Mydata`

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/Myos
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /media/Mydata
```

Now your ntfs partitions are mounted and you can view it's contents on `/media/Myos` and `/media/Mydata` directories.

To make your ntfs partitions  automatically mounted on boot, then you have to add the following lines on `/etc/fstab` file.

```
# /dev/sda2
UUID=9812314912312E1E  /media/Myos  ntfs  defaults  0  0
# /dev/sda3
UUID=0C76D84876D833E4  /media/Mydata  ntfs  defaults 0  0
```

And you won't need to mount an system reserved ntfs partition(`/dev/sda1`)